# Print a string backwards and shifted once ex: cat = ubd

Tags: java

I have successfully printed my String backwards, but I'm having a hard time getting it to shift forward a letter. My outputs have been numbers instead of letters, so I have tried to convert those numbers back to letters unsuccessfully. There is other code in this as well, but I only need help with this one bit.

```
package inlämningsuppgift4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inlämningsuppgift4 {

public static void word(String w1){

   //char a[]= w1.toCharArray();
    for (int i=w1.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
    //char c = 'a';
    //c = (char) (((c - 'a' - 1) % 26) + 'a');
    {System.out.print(w1.charAt(i));
        }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void word2(String w2){
    for (int j=0;j<w2.length(); j++)
    {System.out.print("*"+w2.charAt(j));

    }
    System.out.println("*");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Ange ett ord: ");
String ord = input.nextLine();
word2(ord);
word(ord);

}
}
```

It seems like I was on the right path trying to set up "//char c" but I couldn't get it to function as written. I got that code from a questions search, but can't wrap my head around it. How do I make it fit with my code already written? Or should I find a different way?

Comment: What's *shifting forward a letter*?

Comment: Do you mean shifting the character by Caeser's Cipher?

Comment: (char) (w1.charAt(i) + 1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two different problems:

1. reversing a string. There are a lot of ways to do it.

   ```
   String s1 = "cat";
   String s2 = "";
   for (int i =0 ; i < s1.length(); i++) {
      s2 = s1.charAt(i) + s2;
   }
   System.out.println(s2);
   ```

So just create a new string by adding strings backwards.

2. "Shifting" a character, which presumably means taking the code-point and modifying it, and possibly wrapping it (eg: `Z` wraps to `A`, instead of moving forward to `[`)

   ```
   String s1 = "cat";
   String s2 = "";
   for (int i =0 ; i < s1.length(); i++) {
      char c = s1.charAt(i);
      c += 1;

      // reverse string implementation omitted
   }
   System.out.println(s2);
   ```

Java seems to let you add directly to `char` so whatever works. Note that this does not care about wrapping, so `z` would not wrap to `a`. That's up to you to figure out.

Now you just need to combine that with the string building.

Comment: Your second snippet will just print an empty string.

Comment: @MxyL Thank you. This worked well, I added the char c in the beginning of my code and was able to use it with my original backwards code. Perfect!